# Start an android service when step data is inserted into Google FIT

Tags: android, background-service, google-fit

I am new to Android programming and need your input to develop an app that uses Google FIT data.

I would like to create an Android Service that must be started automatically whenever any 3rd party Fitness apps inserts step data into Google FIT. My service will then read the delta of the step data. I need help in understanding how to implement this technically in Android.

Eg: I have written a GMS service that is started automatically when Android Wear makes a call to mobile app. I am looking for a similar functionality / service that has to start when data is inserted into Google FIT.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you for your time in advance.